# Why can no other chemical elements be used for making a light bulb filament?

Tags: electricity, material-science, physical-chemistry

As far as I can see from [this Wikipedia article on the incandescent light bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb), there have been only four types of light bulb filaments: those made of [carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon), those made of [osmium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium), those made of [tantalum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum) and those made of [tungsten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten) (wolfram). I wonder why it is impossible to use any other chemical element for that purpose. Is there a simple explanation of that reason?

Comment: It might be worth noting, though not directly related to the question, that filaments for heaters are not usually made of tungsten. Heaters exposed to the air, like space heaters, often use a corrosion-resistant alloy of nickel and chromium called, unsurprisingly, nichrome, or a proprietary iron-chromium-aluminum alloy with slightly better properties called kanthal.

Comment: Vacuum tubes typically used tungsten filaments, but later ones coated the tungsten in other materials (some "indirectly-heated" ones even just used it to heat a block of other material) with lower electron work function, which lowered the temperature they needed to operate at (and could have thus used other materials, though it doesn't look like they actually did; tungsten has other properties that make it a good choice). Some gas-filled tubes used an alloy of tungsten with a small amount of thorium, the radioactivity of which lowered the striking voltage by slightly preionizing the gas.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *impossible* to use anything other than those four, rather there is no compelling reason *not* to use one of those four.

Comment: and don't forget that osmium and tantalum are rare and expensive.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Essentially: carbon, osmium, tantalum, and tungsten, along with [rhenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenium), are the only (known, stable) elements that have *melting points high enough to remain solid* at the high temperatures required to achieve the colors of standard incandescent light bulbs.

Why? Incandescent light bulbs produce light by heating a filament, which gets so hot that it emits enough radiation to light up the room. We can model the color of the light bulb well by approximating it as a blackbody at thermal equilibrium, governed by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Planck%27s_law_of_black-body_radiation). When electricity is passed through it, the light bulb filament heats up until it reaches, at equilibrium, the temperature referred to on the bulb label. The colder the temperature, the redder the bulb, and the higher the temperature, the bluer the bulb.

Standard incandescent light bulbs have temperatures between 2700 K and 3000 K. This is because the temperature that produces a peak at the red-most end of the visible spectrum (with $\lambda=750$ nm) is ~3800 K. Thus, as as filament temperature is reduced below 3800 K, the peak will shift further out of the visible range and the light produced will appear dimmer (due to [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law)) and so colder temperatures appear too dim to function as a light bulb.

As the filament temperature is increased, however, the operational temperature of the light bulb approaches the melting point of the filament. Since the temperature is just the *mean* kinetic energy of molecules, many of the molecules in the filament would have more energy individually than that mean, severely reducing the lifetime of a light bulb with a filament whose operational temperature is too close to its melting point. This is why incandescent bulbs are [rarely rated above 3000 K](https://www.prolampsales.com/pages/color-temperature) (at least those without some kind of special coating that makes them bluer).

However, the only elements with melting points above 3000 K are the elements you mention: carbon, osmium, tantalum, and tungsten, with the exception of rhenium, one of the rarest elements on earth. See the elements in red (which have melting points at or above 3000 K) in the following periodic table (from [ptable.com](https://ptable.com/#Properties/MeltingPoint)):

[image: Periodic table from ptable.com listing element melting points, in Kelvin. Red elements have melting points above 3000 K and blue elements have melting points below 300 K.]

That doesn't mean there aren't other materials with high melting points that might function well as filaments for an incandescent bulb, such as [tantalum carbide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_carbide) (which can melt at around 3900 K), for example. Here's a [1935 patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2072788A/en) for a tantalum carbide lamp. Even rhenium has been considered. Here's a [2001](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6624577B2/en) patent for a tungsten-rhenium alloy filament, although given the rarity of rhenium, it is likely not economical to use as a filament for consumer-grade light bulbs.

Non-incandescent light bulbs produce light through entirely different mechanisms, or else don't use a solid filament, which is why LED light bulbs don't require tungsten et al. at all.

Comment: Your periodic table suggests Rhenium as a possibility, and it seems it was sometimes used as part of a tungsten-rhenium alloy filament

Comment: I suspect there might be a handful of other alternatives, but then economics and performance will be big factors in choosing which to use. In fact, if performance is taken into account, then economics is a major factor driving the use of tungsten.

Comment: There's some tungsten in LED bulbs! Though not very much at all. A titanium-tungsten alloy is used in semiconductors as part of the multilayered stack of metals for making good ohmic contact to silicon (and silicon carbide as well).

Comment: @Henry I hadn't considered rhenium! I added a mention to it in my answer.

Comment: @matt_black You have a point about economics, although the question was about light bulbs in general, not just consumer-grade products. There may be advantages for specialized purposes for more expensive filaments--this may be why almost all of the elements with high melting points have been made into filaments at one point or another. Perhaps cost plays a part in the lack of rhenium filament bulbs, though, so I added that to my answer.

Comment: At a class many decades ago with a math professor who loved to make off-topic remarks I learned that the vapor pressure of tungsten is thought to be equivalent to one atom per universe. If true, it would explain why tungsten simply doesn't vaporize, albeit slowly, while in service. (I have no idea what the relative vapor pressures of the other high-temperature melt-point elements are.)

Comment: @RosesBouquet vapor pressure depends on the temperature as well. Maybe they meant the vapor pressure at room temperature

Comment: @user253751 Yeah it's difficult to imagine tungsten can't vapourize at *any* temperature.

Comment: @RosesBouquet Tungsten does vaporize (or at least sputter?) quite rapidly in service in halogen bulbs (which run hotter than regular ones for better efficiency and brightness). It just turns out that having the bulb full of a halogen gas at low pressure creates a chain of chemical reactions that deposits the tungsten back on the filament. That's why the halogen is there--it lets you run them hotter.

Comment: @user253751 - that could very well be the case. Temperature would of course be a factor. I think the professors point was that tungsten was an ideal element, perhaps the best one to use as a filament in an incandescent lamp where the temperatures are so intense. Funny that an off-the-cuff comment might be relevant so many years later.

Comment: @Hearth-Temperature definitely would have an effect on the vapor pressure of tungsten. There must be data somewhere on how it affects tungstens vapor pressure, and possibly how it would compare to the other elements mentioned above. I remember reading about how Edison first achieved success with a light element that would last for a number of hours (as opposed to minutes or seconds) by coating the element he was testing in carbon. My guess has always been that some of the carbon oxidized to CO2 creating an inert gas within the bulb that prevented the metal in the element itself from oxidizing.

Comment: Love the periodic table (from ptable.com)! What a wonderful way to display a single physical property across all the elements! Very effective!

Comment: "don't require tungsten et al. at all." Nice end, haha +1

Comment: So the peak is *never* in the visible spectrum, because that would require a temperature too high for any economically viable material?

Comment: @Douglas Correct. The only pure element with a melting temperature >3800 K, when the peak enters the visible range, is carbon. But even then, bulb lifetime would be reduced severely due to filament vaporization (and redeposition onto the glass bulb, causing darkening). Additionally, harmful UV light would be produced in the tail of the Planck distribution that would require filtering. In fact, halogen lamps run hotter than incandescents, so they must filter UV and redeposit vaporized material on the filament. This gives them thermal spectral peaks closer to the visible range!

Answer (score 3):

Although the question has been excellently answered by @abeta201, my question will serve as a history lesson and how tungsten outperformed other metals.

---

Various physicists and scientist started to conceptualize device that will produce light on sending electricity. Joseph Swan was able to demonstrate such a working device but faltered with the reasoning for lack of vacuum and adequate supply of electricity but once better vacuum pumps were available, he started working on device which used carbonized paper filaments/carbon rods. Side-by-side, Thomas Edison also started his own research and filed his own patent. He once moved to platinum but again returned to carbon (due to cost). The first successful test was lasted 13.5 hours and his patent was approved and the device was commercialized to be used in lampposts.

Carbon filaments have a negative temperature coefficient of resistance—as they get hotter, their electrical resistance decreases. This made the lamp sensitive to fluctuations in the power supply, since a small increase of voltage would cause the filament to heat up, reducing its resistance and causing it to draw even more power and heat even further. However, it required 3 watts per candle of light. So, everybody started to  think of alternatives and they found metallic filaments.

At the wake of 20th century, various metals were tested. In 1902, Osmium was used as filament and it made a fairly satisfactory bulb requiring 1.5 watt per candle of light. A number of osmium lamps has been started to be used in Germany but the rarity and cost prevented the commercial introduction on a large scale. In 1904, bulbs made of tantalum has started to be used requiring 2 watts per candle but had a greater life expectancy only when used in direct current and not alternating current.

Following year, bulbs with tungsten filament were started to be used requiring 1.25 watt per candle of light and had a greater life expectancy in both AC and DC and it was started to be commercialized at a global level and then no one had looked for any other metal ever. Now, why tungsten worked and outperformed?

1. Highest Melting point (3410°C) and it can be operated at higher temperature and higher the operating temperature, higher the luminous efficacy. (Osmium was also near - 3050°C) but lack of thermal stability and cost precluded extensive use. Tantalum with m.p 2950°C worked better on DC)
2. Tungsten's vapor pressure as a function of temperature is the lowest among all conductive metals. This reduces bulb blackening.
3. Tungsten is a selective emitter; its emissivity is visible spectrum is higher than in the infrared spectrum. This contributed to the efficacy at the temperature level.
4. Low specific resistance, so it was suited for heavy current
5. Required only 1.25 watt per candlepower (Carbon -3, Tantalum -2)
6. Higher life expectancy - 1000 hour on either current (Carbon: 400-500, Tantalum: DC -600, AC-800)
7. Unlick carbo, tungsten has a positive temperature coefficient, so not it was stable but also gave a whitish light.
8. It was possible to repair a tungsten filament lamp by vigorously shaking it with current on. The broken ends of filament will come in contact and weld together.

Some refractory carbides and nitrides(e.g. TaC, HfC|ZrC, ZrN) have higher melting points than tungsten and enhanced spectral selectivity, however they are thermall unstable at higher temperatures and too brittle to be fabricated into a lamp filaments.

[image]

**References**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb
2. *Power and the Engineer*, Volume 34, Hill Publishing Company, **1911**
3. *Census of Electrical Industries: 1917: Central electric light and power stations with summary of the electrical industries*,  United States. Bureau of the Census U.S. Government Printing Office, **1910**
4. Lamps and Lighting, M.A. Cayless, Routledge, **2012**